# Problems with simple fake URL with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make it so that the following URL:

`http://www.example.com/avatar/100/120/BetaBlaze4.png`

Turns into this:

`http://www.example.com/avatargen/generate.php?x=100&y=120&for=BetaBlaze4`

I am having troubles however, because I really honestly have no idea what I am doing with htaccess (I'm new to it.) Here's the current code. Forewarning, it's probably completely wrong lol.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^avatar/(.+)$/(.+)$/(.+)$.png avatargen/generate.php?x=$1&y=$2&for=$3 [L,NC]
```

All suggestions welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... The $ usually means the end of the line, so multiple `$` is not going to probably work... I moved it to after `png`. I have put in `\d` assuming that your folders are numeric, but you could stick with `.+` if that doesn't work. It is just that `.+` is "dangerous" since it will match your slashes as well (if there happens to be a third slash in the URL).

```
RewriteRule ^avatar/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.+)\.png$ avatargen/generate.php?x=$1&y=$2&for=$3 [L,NC]
```